# How to turn off Latex/MathJax buffer symbol conversion in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, mathjax

Whenever I write, say, `\Rightarrow` inside of $$, I immediately see the actual right-pointing arrow substituted in. Unfortunately, this does not travel well between GUI-based Emacs and Emacs started `-nw` in a terminal. Research tells me this is a `latex-math-preview-*` (or is it something with `org-preview-latex-default-process`?) feature, and this substitution is happening as Emacs (through imagemagick?) creates actual images to insert in-line when it sees Latex/MathJax blocks. My question is, How do I turn this feature completely off in the buffer? I'm on Emacs 26.3 and (elpa) org-mode latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're seeing the image preview via `imagemagick`/`dvisvgm`, I think you might be seeing a unicode overlay maybe?

If it is, according to [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) you should be able to toggle it with `C-c C-x \` looking at the variable `org-pretty-entities` in `M-x customize-variables` may help you.

Comment: You were right, i.e., not related to imagemagick or dvipng at all. `org-pretty-entities` was nilI, but I had `#+STARTUP: entitiespretty` in the header.